# full-join issue in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables total_sales_store :

```
store.   total_sales
23    198750953.849999
29    77141561.3099999
9     77789512.9899997
15    89133935.9200002
3     57586980.0699998
32    166819624.16
26    143416610.79
12    144287538.149999
35    131520910.08
6     223756634.64
43    90565869.4100002
21    108118179.92
27    253856294.88
38    55159990.42
7   81598450.1399996
```

and storesdata:

```
store. type
1      A
2      A
3      B
4      A
5      B
6      A
7      B
8      A
9      B
10     B 
11     A
```

I want to full join the two table so that I have this desired table:

```
store.             Type.            totalsales
1                   A                   123124
2                   B                  141221
3                   C                   134141
4                   A.                  234234
5                   B                    2323
6                   C                   123214
...
```

So I used the following query:

```
SELECT A.Store,a.total_sales 
FROM totalsales_store A
FULL JOIN
(
    SELECT [Type], Store
    FROM storesdata
) B
    ON A.Store = B.Store
ORDER BY total_sales DESC
```

But what I got is this:

[enter image description here][3]

which neglects the Type column. What can I do to make this work? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not even sure that you need a full outer join here.  Please _edit_ your question, and include all sample data as _text_, directly in the question.  Then, show us the output you expect and explain why.

Answer (score 0):

With a FULL JOIN you will get all results from both tables, even when they don't match each other, so you should account for the NULL store values across tables. Otherwise simply include the Type column in the select.

I didn't see a need for a sub-query.

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(A.Store, B.Store) Store,
    B.Type,
    a.total_sales
FROM
    totalsales_store A
    FULL JOIN storesdata B ON
        A.Store = B.Store
ORDER BY
    a.total_sales DESC
```

I suspect you can get away with

```
SELECT
    A.Store,
    B.Type,
    a.total_sales
FROM
    totalsales_store A
    JOIN storesdata B ON
        A.Store = B.Store
ORDER BY
    a.total_sales DESC
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes much more sense than my original query.

Comment: Please don’t forget to mark this as the accepted answer if Jason provided the solution you needed.

Comment: @Jason . . . The second query is the right query, but the `ISNULL()` is not needed.  Otherwise, I would upvote.

Comment: Yeah, ... agreed. Was just copy/pasted the second one as an example for the OP, but I removed the ISNULL for completeness sake.